# User input string to array with no max line needed

Tags: java, arrays, string, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to get the user's input, then store the input into an array but there is a problem... i want the for cycle to end once the user type '  ' (space). Any help would be appreciated!

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] array = new String[10];
        System.out.println("Insira 10 linhas");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = scn.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println(array[0]);
```

Comment: What have you attempted?  You don't even try to check for a space here.

Comment: Look at branching to control the `for` loop. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check for space after user input and break the loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] array = new String[10];
    System.out.println("Insira 10 linhas");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = scn.nextLine();
        if (array[i].equals(" ")) break;
    }

    System.out.println(String.join(",", array));
}
```

Comment: Please don't just post a "just minor fixes to your code" code-dump answer, but rather *explain* the answer so that it is useful and helpful to future visitors who come to this site looking for solutions to similar problems, since after all, this is the whole purpose of the site. The [answer] link can help guide you with suggestions on how to improve this and your future answers.